# Report Build number in Blazemeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, blazemeter

I am able to  execute PT from Jenkins on Blazemeter.

Now I want jenkins build number to show in blazemeter report. I am doing the below things

1. I am adding sample_variable = buildnumber in user.properties file and uploading the same in blazemeter.
2. In the jmx script as part of test plan I am adding - 
   buildnumber `${__P(buildnumber,0)}`
3. In Jenkins blazemeter plugin i am providing Session properties = -Jbuildnumber=${BUILD_NUMBER}

I am able to see the buildnumber value in Jenkins Logs but I'm not able to harvest the logs in JTL file and Blazemeter. Please suggest what more steps are required.

Also I tried the below workaround, but the same is also not working.

To add it to the JTL, you can add a "Once only controller" with a dummy sampler, and call that sampler buildnumber `${__P(buildnumber,0)}`.
    This way, this label will run only once, and will appear in the JTL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add build number to jtl you can change the jtl file name using the property buildnumber by changing the `Filename` of the listener to for example

```
results-${__P(buildnumber,0)}.jtl
```

Comment: I have add the same as the label name in the Jmeter script, as i need the build number in all the transactions.